# How to expose Command classes to XAML views through View Models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple MVVM architecture where I'm using a view model to bind commands to a xaml view. My commands are fairly generic and I'll be binding them to a couple of views so I've put them into their own classes implementing the `ICommand` interface. Inside of the view model I have public accessors like so:

```
    private ICommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myCommand == null)
            {
                _myCommand = new MyCommand(_injectedModel);
            }

            return _myCommand ;
        }
    }
```

This all works and I'm happy with the architecture but ... I have tons of these functions. They all roughly do the same thing - expose the command as a public property, check if a private command already exists and if so use it otherwise create a new command. It's a bit "boilerplate" for my taste.

I would like a nice way to abstract this. I could create a method that looks up commands based on an identifier from some sort of command map. I could just create all of my commands in the view models constructor (rather than doing so lazily).

What would you consider best practice? Should I avoid instantiating a new command inside each view model and have a central command lookup?

Comment: Note that you can consolidate this with the syntax: `return _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new MyCommand(_injectedModel));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could just create all of my commands in the view models constructor (rather than doing so lazily).

I often do this.  The cost of a command is fairly cheap, in most implementations.  Depending on your implementation, it's likely just a small class with a single delegate reference (or a pair of delegate references).  This is unlikely to be significant enough overhead, IMO, to warrant the lazy construction.

I often write this as:

```
// Constructor
public MyViewModel()
{
    this._injectedModel = SetModel();

    this.MyCommand = new MyCommand(_injectedModel); 
}

ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }
```

Comment: It certainly is a lot cleaner this way. I'm also looking into some IoC frameworks so I can avoid passing around my models so I might move my commands into such a framework as well. I think you're right about the size of the commands being small enough not to worry about extra instantiations - I'm keeping them as stateless as possible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/). It maps ViewModel methods to x:Name in XAML.
You won't need the "boilerplate" code for commands anymore.

Example:

```
<Button x:Name="Save" />
```

Will call:

```
public void Save()
{
   //Save logic
}
```

On button click.
Notice that at no point i made any Command, it's all done behind the scene.

This is a very simple example, you can add parameter(s) to the call and make it use a different event than Click.

Comment: That isn't what I want to do at all. I don't want to delegate command execution to the viewModel at all - I *want* separate classes for the commands so that they can be reused by more than one viewModel. What is the point of doing MVC (or MVVM) if all of your logic just ends up back in the view or the viewModel? Besides if I wanted to do what you have there I'd just use the XAML Click property.

Comment: MVVM is putting the logic in the ViewModel. If you want a separate class for commands, check out static commands. You could also simply route the event to another class.